# Solve functional equation $f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2f(x)f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

**The statement of the problem** : Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ with the 2 properties :

1. $f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2f(x)f(y) ,   \forall x , y \in \mathbb R$
2. There exists a "the smallest" strictly positive number **a**, with the property that **f(a)** is the maximum of the function and **f(a)>0** .

Prove that **f** is a periodic function with period **a**.

**My approach** :

For $x = y = 0 \implies 2f(0) = 2f(0)^2$ so  $f(0)\in\{0,1\}$;

If $f(0) = 0 \implies 2f(x)=0 \implies f(x)=0 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ , so it's clearly periodic.(**EDIT** actually it is false because if the function was 0 then it would not correspond with 2) so f(0) is necessarily 1).

Now if $f(0) = 1$ , for $x = 0$ we get $f(y) + f(-y) = 2f(y) \implies f(y)=f(-y) , \forall x \in \mathbb R $ . So it is enough to determine $f$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

**EDIT** : so I managed to prove that f(a)=1 and that the final answer might be something related to a trigonometric function , probably cosine , since $cos(-x)=cos(x)$ as above.I don't really have any ideas about how I should continue, but I'm waiting for suggestions or solutions.

Any and all proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ everywhere then property $2$ is violated.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, specifically, I agree that $f(x+a)=f(a) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ would result in $f$ being periodic, but by contradiction that implies $\exists x, f(x-a)<f(a)$ and $\exists x, f(x+a)<f(a)$. You stated that implies $f(x-a)<f(a)$ and $f(x+a)<f(a)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which is not necessarily true.

Comment: If $f(a)$ is a maximum it doesn’t mean that there is no other $x$ such that $f(a)=f(x)$. Also the negation of $\forall x: P(x)$ is $\exists x: \lnot P(x)$, not $\forall x: \lnot P(x)$.

Comment: It is clear that $f(a) = 1$ because $1 = f(0)\le f(a)$ and $f(a)f(y)\le (f(a+y) + f(a -y))/2 \le f(a)$, hence $f(y)\le 1$ but this applies to $y = a$ too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.Now that I read I realize that my solution is almost entirely wrong. what solutions do you propose?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = \cos(x)$ is a solution. Using $x = y = a/2$ implies that $f(a/2)=-1$, then $f(a/4) = 0$ with $x = y = a/4$

Comment: "Since f(a) is the maximum of our function ⟹f(x−a)<f(a) "  Not if $x -a > a$ or $x-a \le 0$.  "Because if for exemple f(x+a)=f(a),∀x∈R, which would result in f being periodic, so we don't want that. "  $f(x+a) = f(a)$ **for all $x$** is not the only option.  You can have $f(x+a) = f(a)$ for *some but not all $x$*.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for pointing that out.what solution do you propose to this problem?

Comment: @Gribouillis Isn’t it rather $f(x)=\cos(2\pi\frac xa)$

Comment: Doesn't the constant $f(x)=1$ satisfy the conditions? Or is $a$ supposed to be a strict maximum as well?

Comment: @BobbyOcean well the function cannot be a constant because otherwise there would not be *a* the smallest strictly positive number a such that f(a) is maximum , so the condition 2) will fail

Comment: @BobbyOcean No, it violates the second property. There must exist the smallest positive $a$

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2f(x) = f(x+0) + f(x-0) = 2f(x)f(0)$ for all $x$.  If there exist any $w$ so that $f(w) \ne 0$ then $2f(w) =2f(w)f(0)$ and $f(0)=1$.  And if $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ that violates property 2.  So $f(0) = 1$.

$f(a+a) +f(a-a) = 2f^2(a)$ so $f(2a)+1 = 2f^2(a)$.   But $f(a) \ge 1$.  But if $f(a) > 1$ we'd have $f(2a) + 1 \le f(a) + 1< f(a)+f(a) \le f^2(a) + f^2(a) =2f^2(a) = f(2a)+1$.  That's a contradiction so $f(a) = f(0) = 1$.

It follows that $f(2a) + 1=2f^2(a)=2$ so $f(2a) =1$ and by strong induction that $f(na) = f(a) =1$.  [suppose $f(ka) =f(a)=1$ for all $k \le n$ then $f(na + a) + f(na-a)= 2f(na)f(a)=2$.  But $f(na+a) + f(na-a)=f((n+1)a) + f((n-1)a) = f((n+1)a) + 1$ so $f((n+1)a) = 1 =f(a)$.]

Now consider $f(x+a) + f(x-a) = 2f(x)f(a) = 2f(x)$.  If $f(x+a) \ne f(x-a)$, wolog $f(x-a) < f(x+a)$, then there is a positive $d$ so that $f(x-a) = f(x)-d; f(x+a)=f(x) + d$.

This leads to a bit of problem $f(x + 2a)+f(x) = f((x+a)+a)+f((x+a)-a)=2f(x+a)f(a)=2f(x) + 2d$ so $f(x+2a) = f(x)+2d$ and by induction for any natural $n$ we get $f(x + na) = f(x) + nd$.  But by archimedian principal we can find an $n$ are $f(x+na)=f(x) + nd > f(a)$.  A contradiction.

So $f(x+a) =f(x-a)$ and $f(x+a)+f(x-a) = 2f(x)$ so $f(x+a)= f(x-a) =f(x)$ for all $x$.  (Note if $f(x-a) > f(x+a)$ our argument would have let to $f(x-na) =f(x)+nd>f(a)$ for some positive $d$ and natural $n$)

Comment: Great reasoning! It is probably worth to note that due to the property $2$ there is no such $t$ that $a>t>0$ and $\forall x: f(x)=f(x+t)$. I guess, the necessity of this depends on the definition of a function with a certain period

Comment: in the second paragraph, why is $f(a)\geq1$?

Comment: @PNDas Because $f(a)$ is the maximum of the function from property 2. So $f(a) \ge f(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

(Too big for a comment), If we additionally assume that $f$ is $C^2(\mathbb{R})$, then this regularity condition uniquely determines the type of the function. Subtracting both sides by $2f(x)$ and then taking the limit as $y$ goes to zero. We obtain, $$ \frac{1}{y^2}(f(x+y)+f(x-y)-2f(x))=\frac{2}{y^2}f(x)(f(y)-1)$$ or $f''(x) = 2f(x)\left(\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f(y)-1}{y^2}\right) = Lf(x)$, where $L = \lim_{y\to 0} f''(y)$ (Obtained via LH rule).  Since the function $f$ is bounded, $L < 0$ and $f(x) = \cos{(\sqrt{-L}x)}$. I have used the boundary conditions that
$f(0)  =1$ and by taking partial derivative with respect to $y$ and plugging in $x=y=0$, $f'(0) = 0$. The function achieves maximum value at $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{-L}}$, therefore from property 2, $a = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{-L}}$ and $f$ is periodic with period $a$, thus $$ \boxed{f(x) = \cos{\left(\frac{2\pi}{a}x\right)} }$$

Comment: I'd like to see an example of a non ${\cal C}^2$ solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer

Plugging in $y = 0$ gives us $2f(x) = 2f(x)f(0)$, so $f(0) = 1$.  ($f(x) = 0$ would also be a solution, but would violate property #2.)

Plugging in $x = 0$ gives us $f(y) + f(-y) = 2f(0)f(y)$.  From this, and the previous result that $f(0) = 1$, we get $f(-y) = f(y)$.  In other words, $f$ is an *even* function.

Plugging in $y = x$ gives us $f(2x) + f(0) = 2f(x)^2$, or $f(2x) = 2f(x)^2 - 1$.  The same result can be obtained with $y = -x$, since $f$ is an even function.

Let $M = f(a)$ be the maximum value of the function.  By the recurrence relation $f(2x) = 2f(x)^2 - 1$, we have $f(2a) = 2M^2 - 1$.  Because $M$ is the maximum value of $f$, we have $2M^2 - 1 \le M$, or $2M^2 - M - 1 \le 0$.  Equivalently, $-\frac{1}{2} \le M \le 1$.  But since we know that $f(0) = 1$, them $M \ge 1$.  Thus, the only possible value of $M$ is $M = 1$.  So, $f(2a) = 2\times 1^2 - 1 = 1$.  Similarly, $f(4a) = 2f(2a)^2 - 1 = 2\times 1^2 - 1 = 1$.  And continuing this reasoning, we get $\forall n \in\mathbb{N} : f(2^na) = 1$.

Now, plug $y = a$ into the original equation, getting $f(x+a) + f(x-a) = 2f(x)f(a)$.  Since $f(a) = 1$, this means $f(x+a) + f(x-a) = 2f(x)$.  And similarly, $f(x+2^na) + f(x-2^na) = 2f(x)$.

The recurrence $f(x+a) + f(x-a) = 2f(x)$ can easily be satisfied by any function that's $a$-periodic (so $f(x - a) = f(x) = f(x + a)$).  However, right now I'm struggling to prove that this is a *necessary* condition on $f$, so for now I'm marking my answer as "partial".